# Object and Collection Initializers - assign self?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using object and collection Initializers in the program and thinking how to get the example below.

```
Orders.Add(new Order()
                {
                  id = 123,
                  date = new datetime(2012,03,26)
                  items = new OrderItems()
                          { 
                             lineid = 1,
                             quantity = 3,
                             order = ?? // want to assign to current order.
                          }
                 }
```

How can I assign the newly created order to the order item?

Comment: You might want to just add the OrderItems collection first and then assign the order. Or you might be okay with a one-way relationship.

Comment: Seems kind of odd from a modeling perspective.  Why does an `OrderItem` contain an `Order`?  I would think that the `Order` is the aggregate root and contains items with additional context about those items (`OrderItem`s).  But those items don't really need to know anything about the order.

Comment: As a workaround, you can make the setter for `items` assign the property transparently, although that won't work for `OrderItem`s added to the collection later.

Comment: @David It could be an artifact of an ORM being used. Most people don't go through the bother of hiding the foreign key from children to parents in a 1:N relationship in the mapping; if the property is there already, it's better to keep it set to the right value for the sake of consistency. (Not ideal from a design POV, but there you go.)

Comment: Yes, it is existing semantic model I would like to keep them consistent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're trying to here isn't possible.  You can't refer to the object being constructed from within an object initializer body.  You will need to break this up into a set of separate steps

```
var local = new Order() {
  id = 123,
  date = new datetime(2012, 03, 26);
};
local.items = new OrderItems() {
  lineid = 1;
  quantity = 3;
  order = local;
};
Orders.Add(local);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Order.items` is a property, you can put something like this in the property setter

```
public class Order
{
    private OrderItems _items;
    public OrderItems items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value
            _items.order = this
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just take the order out of the initializer:

```
Orders.Add(new Order()
           {
              id = 123,
              date = new datetime(2012,03,26)
              items = new OrderItems()
                      { 
                         lineid = 1,
                         quantity = 3,
                      }
             }
```

Comment: Thanks, It might be the solution to the example but I'm asking if there is any way during object initializer.

Comment: @laptop, I realize that. As JaredPar mentioned, what you were hoping to do per your example wasn't possible, so this was the best workaround without building each element separately as Jared suggested