# How to get the reference to newly constructed instance in expression tree c#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, projection

Is It possible to get the reference to the `PositionViewModel` in the following expression tree:

```
    public static Expression<Func<Model, ViewModel>> ToViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return x => new PositionViewModel
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Employees = x.Employees.Select(e => new Employee
                {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    Name = e.Name,
                    Position = ??? // reference to PositionViewModel
                }).ToList()
            };
        }
    }
```

I think it is, because EF does that.
Any suggestions?

Edit:
Forgot to mention that "Postition" is of type ViewModel.

Comment: I don't think you can do it within the initializer syntax.

Comment: If `position==this` then initialize it in the constructor maybe? But this is an `Employee` object, why reference a `PositionViewModel`? I'm confused.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question a bit to remove confusion. `this` refers to the current instance of the type in which the code is currently executing. The code in the question is in a static method (so, no current instance), and code wants a reference to another type.

Comment: When does the EF does that? Can't you just look at how how does it do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would spontaneously do it in steps:

```
public static Expression<Func<Model, ViewModel>> ToViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return x => GetViewModel(x);
    }
}

public ViewModel GetViewModel(Model x)
{
    var vm = new PositionViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name
    };

    vm.Employees = x.Employees.Select(p => new Employee
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Position = vm
    }).ToList();

    return vm;
}
```

This way you can still wrap this up as an expression tree.

Comment: That was and my first tough, but this can't be an expression anymore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878184/object-and-collection-initializers-assign-self

Comment: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Comment: @FredrikMörk Thanks. The problem is that if this is not a lambda expression it will leads to n + 1 syndrome.

Comment: @user3049133 See updated answer: by extracting the body into a separate method you can still keep the expression tree.

Comment: @FredrikMörk At first I want to say this is amazing idea!
But LINQ to Entities doesn't like it. However, I think the problem is for another thread.
Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ViewModel GetViewModel(Model)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @user3049133 You can't do that if you want to translate your expression to SQL. All of the code has to be an expression, not a simple expression that calls a method you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to use the fact that `Employees` is a property, so you can add any code you want to its setter. Something like:

```
private IList<Employee> employees;

public IList<Employee> Employees
{
    get
    {
        return employees;
    }

    set
    {
        employees = value;

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            employee.Position = this;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you don't need to do anything in your expression, and the `Position` will be set automatically.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is more correct for my intentions. I wish I had the opportunity to mark two correct answers or at least to give you a plus.