# Is there a way to interact with the object that contains an Action?

Tags: c#, action

I'm working on a project, where I have Interactible objects that have Actions properties.

Something like

```
class Interactible 
{
    Action OnInteract;

    public function DoStuff()
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

I want to edit the "parent" object of an action when making a delegate.

For now, it looks like that :

```
var myObj = new Interactible();
myObj.OnInteract = delegate
{
    myObj.DoStuff();
}
```

Is there a way to do something looking like this ?

```
var myObj = new Interactible 
{
    OnInteract = delegate
    {
        this.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) your code does not compile 2) AFAIK you can't do that, but at least you can skip the manual delegate stuff and just do `myObj.OnInteract = myObj.DoStuff;` letting the compiler fill in the blanks.

Comment: If you actually do C#, take a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event

Comment: You just wrote `this.DoStuff()` inside the body of the "anonymous function", so what is the issue? What is `this` supposed to refer to? As you write it, it refers to the current instance of the class/struct inside which you make the declaration of `myObj`. So that class/struct must have a suitable `DoStuff()` method as well. Syntax remark: Note that since lambdas came into C# (C# 3.0 from 2007), most people prefer writing `() =>` instead of `delegate` in contexts such as yours (but as Guru Stron said in your case your can even use the method group directly).

Comment: My point is to have something that refers myObj to replace this with

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. You shift to the "object initializer" syntax with `new Interactible { ... }`, but then you cannot refer the instance being constructed inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have:

```
var myObj = new Interactible();
myObj.OnInteract = delegate
{
    myObj.DoStuff();
};
```

and your question is if it is possible to rewrite this in [object initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) of C# 3.0.

So you want:

```
var myObj = new Interactible
{
    OnInteract = delegate
    {
        $$$.DoStuff();
    },
};
```

where `$$$` represents a reference to the instance currently being constructed.

But the answer to your question, *Is there a way to do something looking like this*, is no. You cannot do it.

See also [Object and Collection Initializers - assign self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878184/).

Of course you can do:

```
Interactible myObj;
// explicit scope to prevent 'tmp' from being seen later
{   
    var tmp = new Interactible();
    tmp.OnInteract = delegate
    {
        tmp.DoStuff();
    };
    myObj = tmp;
}

// use 'myObj'
```

but it only makes things look uglier, so I guess no-one would prefer it.

Comment: Thank you, at least I know that I cannot do it